# Enable SQL login to view only one database but not to owned it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have server which consists several databases. Next, I created login `user1` which has `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` database roles on `databaseOne` database.

I need to enable for that user to see only `databaseOne` database, and not others, and to not be database owner.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [user1]; 
GO
USE databaseOne;
GO
DROP USER user1;
GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::databaseOne TO [user1];
GO
```

Comment: last statement change authorization, in fact, `user1` became database owner through `dbo` user, am I right? In this situation I can change database definition...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You want user1 to become dbo?

Comment: After you delete user `user1`, login `user1` remains on server and is mapped to `dbo` user at specific database. When I log to the server with `user1` login I see only one database, and that is OK, but I can change database definition, alter tables, and so on, but I want just to read and modify data.

Comment: Without making the user a DBO there is no way to open view ability back up to only one Database. This is not a feature that has ever been added. However, if you grant only db_datareader and db_datawriter, the user can still access the DB by using `USE databaseOne ` command.